# adding a UUID to a neo4j spring data framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

**Background**
I am trying to figure out the correct way to add a UUID to neo4j if I am using Spring Data.

I have seen:
https://dzone.com/articles/assigning-uuids-neo4j-nodes
and here a `TransactionEventHandler` is used to insert a UUID when necessary. But the person who made this tutorial was not using spring data.

I have also seen this person's code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/web/domain/User.java They seem to be using java's java.util.UUID and then just converting it to a string and using it as a string entity and indexing it and going from there. This seems to be the simplest way.

But, in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/ They seem to using UUID's as their example for a usecase of an `AddUuidPreSaveEventListener`

**Questions**

Which method should I use for adding UUID's?

Could I just add

```
...
import java.util.UUID;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Index;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.typeconversion.Convert;
import org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.UuidStringConverter;

...

@Convert(UuidStringConverter.class)
@Index(unique = true, primary = true)
private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

...
```

to my GraphType.java file and call it good?

Note: I am very new to all these technologies and could be still too inexperienced to even properly ask a question on this stuff.

Note 2:
I have seen the graphaware UUID library before, it does seem to be fairly up to date, but I assumed that there may be a preferred way to make UUIDs if I was working with spring data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [GraphAware Neo4j UUID](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) library.

The docs says:

> **GraphAware UUID** is a simple library that transparently assigns a UUID
>   to newly created nodes and relationships in the graph and makes sure
>   nobody can (accidentally or intentionally) change or delete them.

Simply download [GraphAware Neo4j Framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) and GraphAware Neo4j UUID .jar files to `/plugins` directory, modify [few lines](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid#setup-and-configuration) in `neo4j.conf` file and restart Neo4j. After it, `UUIDs` will be assigned to each node / relationships created in the Neo4j graph.

This approach does not depends on Spring or Spring Data.

Comment: I was worried that working with too many differing  libraries may be too complex. Do you know if spring data and graphaware play nice?

Comment: @Romulus I never worked with GraphAware UUID in conjunction with Spring Data, but indeed has no dependencies between these tools. Seems to me this is a great advantage. Think: Why should you delegate the UUID generation for another application layer than the database itself? What will happen if you decide to handle the Neo4j database from another application? You will replicate the UUID generation logic?

Comment: The UUID plugin runs on server side while sdn runs on application side, so they cannot really clash, except if you run embedded but as GraphAware is the main developer team of SDN this should be fine. The only drawback is that the uuid is not returned on node creation, only on the next tx, this is some limitations of neo4j itself and how tx event handlers work.

Comment: what is the difference between randomUUID and GraphAware library ? which one should i use ? @BrunoPeres

Comment: i used Graphaware for the UUID generation and nodes are created fine with the configured UUID and for which how can i model my pojo in Spring boot data neo4j?  I mean, for primaryField, Does "@Id" is enough / "@GeneratedValue" is needed? Any inputs would help @Bruno Peres

Answer (score 2):

There is now an official way to generate UUID in spring data neo4j is by using [UUIDStringGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.0.6/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/core/support/UUIDStringGenerator.html). you can use it like this

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generatorClass = UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    private String id;
```

Then use it in your neo4j repository as a string.